# Is there a barcode reader API in Windows Mobile 5.0/6.0?

Tags: windows-mobile, barcode

How can barcodes be read on Windows Mobile devices?

The reader I am using states that it will support Windows Mobile 5.0, 6.0 and 6.5 phones.

Comment: You mean with a physical barcode scanner or from a photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most mobile devices read the barcode like it is text, so the work is taken care of for you already.

Place a text box on your form, make sure that text box has the focus (that's the biggest training issue we have here), and handle the `Text_Changed` event.

Here's a quasi-code example:

```
TextBox textBox1;

void textBox1_Tex(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal API in the .NET Compact Framework or through P/Invoke.

The manufacturer may provide an SDK for reading barcodes. For example Motorola provide what they call an '[EMDK](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=13209&sliceId=&dialogID=244352316&stateId=1%200%20244348413)' to read barcodes on their devices.

Alternatively, some devices will read the barcodes as plain text from a serial port. Just open the serial port and read what comes in.